# Print value of by loop in the end of line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

My file which run loop...

```
$cat /wdc-cron/countries.csv
c-ac,ascension_island
c-ad,andorra
c-ae,united_arab_emirates
```

My program file

```
yesterday=$(date --date "1 days ago" +%F)

while IFS= read -r line
do

dir=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $1 }')
country=$(echo $line | awk -F, '{print $2 }')

cd /$dir.whoisdatacenter.com

echo $country >> /wdc-cron/count-$yesterday.txt
cat /$dir.whoisdatacenter.com/$yesterday-$country-email.csv | wc -l >> /wdc-cron/count-$yesterday.txt

 awk '{print $country,",",$dir}' 

done < "/wdc-cron/countries.csv"
```

My result is

```
cat count-2020-01-22.txt 
ascension_island
0
andorra
0
united_arab_emirates
32
```

My should I do so result come like

```
ascension_island, 0
andorra, 0
united_arab_emirates, 32
```

I will be very glad if someone can help me out,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to replace the line:

`echo $country >> /wdc-cron/count-$yesterday.txt`

with:

`printf "$country, " >> /wdc-cron/count-$yesterday.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
$ awk '{print $country,",",$dir}'
```

just use the **echo** command.

Comment: I just saw I had unwanted $ before awk... when i write echo.. it show me my code... {print $country,",",$dir}
{print $country,",",$dir}
{print $country,",",$dir}